# Product variants with same sku

Tags: magento, magmi

I need to add a few products with the same sku but different attributes, such as weight and size. How can i do this with using magmi or anyway? As i understant product SKU must be unique.

Comment: In Magento no two products can have same SKU.Way out is to create a configurable product and within that configurable product have your variants as sinmple products.These simple products will have diff skus.With magmi you will be able to upload simple products am not sure whether they have something for importing configurable product

Comment: @SatishMantri Thanks, I tried, but there is one more problem - different variants have different price, but configurable attributes must be dropdown lists is there a way to resolve this new problem?

Comment: As Marius stated below that if you do not care of inventory being different for different sizes then go with custom options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have 2 products with the same SKU.
But there is a workaround for this.
You cannot use configurable products because each combination of attributes must be a standalone simple product, hence different sku.
But you can simulate this using custom options (See the tab 'custom options' in the product edit page in admin).
It has all you need. You can have the same sku, you can have different prices for different custom options.
There is only one drawback.
You cannot have a separate stock for each combination of options. The product can either be in stock or out of stock.
So if you use up the stock for a weight and size you have to manually remove it from the backend.